# How do I anchor RequestMapping to the root?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a page /pledge handled here...

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/pledge", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPledge(Model model) {
```

And I handle products with a String id...

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/products/{id}")
public String showProduct(Model model, @PathVariable("id") String productId) {
```

That's worked well for me. However, if I create a product called "pledge", the path is /products/pledge.  That gets handled by the first method, but I'd like it to be handled by the second.

I'd be most comfortable if the RequestMapping started at the root, it seems like it's working from the end and working back now (maybe later I'll have /users/pledge, /definitions/pledge, etc.).

How do I configure it so that /products/pledge is picked up by the /products/{id} mapping and not by /pledge? Thanks.

Comment: If properly configured this should work as you expect. Any `@ RequestMapping` on your controllers classes?

Comment: Double check that you do not make a mistake in your observation. Spring should invoke the `showProduct` method if you request `http:/localhost:8080/yourApp/products/pledge`

Comment: Nope, no RequestMapping defined on the Controller.

Comment: Please edit and add spring logs, on start, spring is logging its request mapping.